GCP Pub/Sub to BigQuery writing incorrect value to NUMERIC column
I'm publishing JSON to Pub/Sub in the following format:
{"reading":"11202.8"}

Numbers are encoded as strings to force explicit precision. This get written to BigQuery using a Pub/Sub BigQuery Subscription. The column type of reading is NUMERIC.
When I publish an integer (i.e. {"reading":"6533"}) a seemingly random number is written to BigQuery (i.e. -0.000549397).
If I encode it as 6533.0 it appears to be written correctly.
Should I be encoding it different? or is this a bug?

Hi @Matthew Brown, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

This is an issue that needs to be fixed by the Pub/Sub team. The ETA for the fix is September 13, 2024.

When you publish a string value like "6533" to BigQuery, it's initially interpreted as a string. BigQuery then attempts to implicitly convert this string to a numeric type based on the column schema, however it may lead to inconsistencies.
I would suggest publishing a float value in your Pub/Sub message.
{ "reading": 11202.8 }

